Setting custom domain for Expo dev server
I'm working with the react-native Metro Bundler through Expo, and it serves my application using a local address:
image showing local host:port for app

I'd like it to use https://dev.mycustomdomain.net instead of the local IP

I set up a reverse proxy to serve my dev app over HTTPS and would like to access it over Expo Go, but I can't seem to figure out how to configure that unique domain in the configuration file. I'd like to see if that URL can get generated in the scannable QR code too. Using the "Enter URL Manually" option in Expo Go just opens the App in my phone's default web browser, not the native app view I get if I scan the QR code.
I checked the FAQ but couldn't find anything in the config for setting this domain value. Checked the local config files as well for a property, but didn't find anything.
I also explored the public tunneling option but I have a domain that works if I put in the URL manually, so it's not what I'm looking for.
